# Illegal option: -ext Try keytool

Tags: java, linux, keytool

I am using `java version "1.7.0_60"` in linux machine but when trying to run `-keytool` command with `-ext` i am getting

> Illegal option:  -ext Try keytool -help

Can someone please tell me its due to java version issue or something else?

I check [Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html) the have mentioned `-ext` already there in `Java7`

**EDIT:-**

Here is the command

```
keytool -genkey -dname "CN=apptest2, OU=A, O=te ha,L=Delhi, S=Delhi, C=IN" -alias "ssocertificate" -keyalg RSA -keypass P@ssw0rd -keystore /etc/cas/certificate/portal.keystore –storepass storepass -keyalg "RSA" -ext SAN=dns:apptest2,ip:105.210.22.145
```

Answer (score 1):

The option is still available in new Java versions, but it is not a top-level option. It is only applicable following a few particular options. From the man page:

> Denotes an X.509 certificate extension. The option can be used in -genkeypair and -gencert to embed extensions into the certificate generated, or in -certreq to show what extensions are requested in the certificate request. The option can appear multiple times. The name argument can be a supported extension name (see Named Extensions) or an arbitrary OID number. The value argument, when provided, denotes the argument for the extension. When value is omitted, that means that the default value of the extension or the extension requires no argument. The :critical modifier, when provided, means the extension's isCritical attribute is true; otherwise, it is false. You can use :c in place of :critical.

You can see its help if you ask for help on an option like `-gencert`. E.g.,

```
% keytool -help -gencert
keytool -gencert [OPTION]...
Options:
...
 -ext <value>       X.509 extension
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. System Path has multiple versions of JAVA reference. Removed the multiple references and installed the latest java version. This issue got fixed.